# How to use Kafka Transactional Producer with Schema Registry with multiple Schema Records?

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am looking into the [Transactional producer](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) that Kafka supports and the [Exactly-Once](https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/) processing described in these 2 links:
1) https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/
2) https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

It seems very elegant solution for streaming scenarios where the consumer can poll the record (from topic A for example), process the record and publish to multiple output topics (say B and C) and the change-log topic. This can happen atomically as described in the links if transaction API for producer is used correctly.

Unfortunately, the definition of Kafka Producer includes the types of key and value. `IProducer<Key, Value>` (https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.IProducer-2.html)

and if we have multiple schema definitions for various records in our topics we have a problem where we need to define one producer per schema. Given that choice, we can't have atomic transaction that spans multiple output sink topics.

Unless I am missing something, Transactional Kafka support for producer seems to be very restrictive. In production, it is very practical to define schema in Schema Registry to deal with evolving schema and forward and backward compatibility.

I thought of using `IProducer<byte[], byte[]>` for the transactional producer and serialize/deserialize the message, but I am not sure if this is the best way to go about it. Is this the only viable solution with the current state of Kafka Transaction support?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you have different types of data, you can write a common serializer that automatically serializes given data item as per the topic.

In the [ISerializer](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.ISerializer-1.html) you have the following method

```
byte[] Serialize(T data, SerializationContext context)
```

The `SerializationContext` contains the `topic` property. ([Reference](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/api/Confluent.Kafka.SerializationContext.html))

Alternatively, you can also make use of `Headers` to store some important information on how to serialize them.

I don't know .NET, but I suppose you can write a wrapper class around each type that you want to produce and your *actual* object (data) will be a property in that class which you can *get*.

The *actual* object can then be serialized as per its type or the topic name or some info in the header.